# How to make it so cookies are fixed and not able to be edited

Tags: php, cookies

My website uses cookies and I've noticed that I'm able to change the value of the cookies with a chrome plugin. Is there a way to make it so people cannot edit the cookie? I've been thinking of writing a script to check if the cookie changes but I'm not sure if this would work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you don't want people to edit their cookies, you could sign them and discard cookies that fail the signature match. It's typically a sign that something else in your application design is wrong, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, cookies are stored on the client side and you don't have any control over them. You have to validate them on the server prior use every single time. When it comes to web development, you need to see your clients as a potential security liability. You can't trust them.

If you want to make it a little harder for the attacker, you can encrypt contents of your cookies, but the fact they're on the client side means the attacker can try to decrypt them and modify as wishes...

=> If you have data you need to keep away from users, don't use cookies for that. You should use Session in that case.

Comment: is there a way to set a session that will last for days?

Comment: @JoeScotto, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to do a basic login system. I have the whole thing working with my current code but the only issue is that the user ID is stored in a cookie. I know this is bad practice but I don't know any other way to do it. I've been thinking about encrypting the id in the cookie.

Comment: @JoeScotto: why do you want to save the user ID in a cookie? Is that to remember them if they sign out? (Hopefully this is not to signify they are signed in! Cookies are trivially editable on the client, and you don't want people to specify which account they are signed in as).

Comment: What would be the best method to remember if they were signed in?

Comment: @JoeScotto, look at this for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589595/php-persistent-login-do-i-reissue-a-cookie-after-every-page-authentication and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960136/persistent-login-using-cookies-and-session-variables

Comment: @walther So basically a really long encrypted string stored as a cookie that indicates their ID?

Comment: @JoeScotto, there are many ways you can tackle this... Not sure which one is "best", opinions vary. But yes, you should use a token instead, definitely not the ID. If you need to make it a bit more secure, you can check for more variables, like the browser, IP address etc. and store them on the server.. Then when the user comes back, you can compare these things to be a little bit more sure that the user is really the one he says he is. It's a kinda broad topic without any definitive solution I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm gonna mess around with SHA-256.